# How does the R survey package svydesign() function adjust for clustering?

Tags: r, survey

R *survey* package svydesign() function adjust for clustering? If I input PSU and school [svydesign(ids=~PSUID+school, weights=~w, data=data1)] how does it work?

Can't find the information anywhere

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider posting a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: hi Moira, are you looking for the `?svydesign` help page or maybe you want to run `debug(survey:::svydesign.survey.design2)` so you can walk through each step after calling `svydesign()` ?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a simple answer to this: it's not just a closed-form expression, it's a recursive computation. It's documented with references in `?svyrecvar`

What it *computes*, though, is the Horvitz-Thompson variance estimator, eg [here](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat506/book/export/html/645)